# Are Depressions in the Skull Normal or At Least Okay

Tags: x-rays, head-trauma, concussion, skull

I went skiing recently and hit the back of my head pretty hard. I had a headache for a few days, but it went away and hasn't really come back. I recently got x-rayed for braces and noticed a depression about where I hit my head (in the back towards the bottom).

[image]

Is this normal, or at least not an issue? I feel like I might be paranoid, but I guess you can never be too safe

Comment: Did you get a copy of the radiologist's read of the XRay? They are extremely thorough in their evaluations, generally mentioning anything abnormal in the report.  We can't offer you advice on your specific situation, especially not interpreting your XRay.  If you are concerned, ask your healthcare provider.

Comment: I don't think there was a radiologist. This is from an orthodontist appointment

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. Requests for personal medical advice are strictly off topic here. But you can rest assured that if you had a depressed skull fracture, you wouldn't be walking around getting orthodontia x-rays and posting on stackexchange. If you really want to be sure, see a physician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a layman, no expert on human skulls.  I do think I can likely help you feel a little less concern perhaps.  The type of xray used by orthodonists typically is called a cephalometric xray or ceph.  The image I see of you seems pretty typical & many seem to show some amount of a thicker area along the occipital bun on the back of the head.  Here is some info on the type of xray & if you link, you will see an image that very much shows a similar bone formation and a little info on the type of xray used.  You can certainly ask your orthodonist about it.  They can tell you what is typical that they see & I am pretty certain had they seen anything unusual, they would speak up immediately.  I had a chiropractor take an xray that showed a sinus tumor.  They didn't tell me that.  They told me I needed to have my dentist do some xray as something looked off in my oral cavity & they have a better resolution to take a look.  It was from a tooth growing in the wrong place & totally treatable.   https://www.verywell.com/definition-of-cephalometric-ceph-x-ray-1059162